# Is the next map a quotient map?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=[0,1] \cup (2,3]$, let $Y=[0,2]$ and suppose $X$ and $Y$ have the usual topologies. Define $f: X \to Y$ by $f(x)=x$ if $x \in [0,1]$ and $f(x)=x-1$ if $x \in (2,3]$.

I tried proving that the function was closed, but I had problems. Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: Hint: is $A=(2,3]$ closed in $X$? What is $f(A)$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Is $(1,2]$ closed in $Y$? Is $f^{-1}\big[(1,2]\big]$ closed in $X$? What would $f$ being a quotient map say about these two sets?

Comment: I have that if $f: X \to Y$ is a quotient map then $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$ if and only if $C$ is closed in $Y$ where $C \subset Y$

Comment: @erika21148: Okay; it can also be defined using open sets. Let me modify my answer to suit your definition.

Comment: I know that $f^{-1}[(1,2])=(2.3]$, but I'm a little confuse if $(2,3]$ is open in $X$ because $X-(2,3]=[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ is closed in $X$. And $Y-(1,2]=[0,1]$

Comment: @erika21148: The question, though, is whether $(2,3]$ is **closed** in $X$. This is true if and only if there is a closed set in $\Bbb R$ whose intersection with $X$ is $(2,3]$. Can you find such a set? As for $(1,2]$, is there a point of $Y\setminus(1,2]$ that is a limit point of $(1,2]$? If so, $(1,2]$ is not closed in $Y$.